# kubectl patch deplyoment results in 'The "" is invalid'

Tags: kubernetes

I try to patch a deployment with the following command:

```
kubectl patch deployment spin-clouddriver -n spinnaker --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts", "value": {"mountPath": "/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts", "subPath": "cacerts", "name": "cacerts"}}]'
```

which results in

```
The  "" is invalid
```

I don't see where is the error nor do I see how the message helps me to find the problem. Any hints?

Comment: Hi, `path": "/spec/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts` you are missing template key, it should be `spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts`

Comment: Thanks @SureshVishnoi that was it. Can you add it as a solution, will give you some points ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct path is `"path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts`.  There was missing template key.